# How to find each values in controller, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I' m newbie in ruby on rails, and i trying to find some values in my controller. But i have one trouble, i can only find one value in my parameters. 
This is my controller:

```
def update
    @var = Book.find_by_jan(params[:ids])
    logger.debug "var: #{@var.id}"
  end
```

Here! my log:

```
Started POST "/welcome/update" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-12 16:53:55 +0700
Processing by WelcomeController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"ids"=>"9784331516997,9784309978147,"}
  [1m[36mBook Load (3.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."jan" = 9784331516997 LIMIT 1[0m
var: 1809
```

Can you see that? I can only find Book with jan = 9784331516997, not with 9784309978147.
I want to find my books with each values: "978433151699" and "9784309978147". So, please help me!

Comment: Please show the code for `Book.find_by_jan`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find_by`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-by) returns only the first element which matches the query:

> Model.find_by finds the first record matching some conditions. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> Client.find_by first_name: 'Lifo'
> # => #<Client id: 1, first_name: "Lifo">
>
> Client.find_by first_name: 'Jon'
> # => nil
> ```

To find all element matching the query, use `where`:

```
Book.where(jan: params[:ids].split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `where` but pars your data

```
Book.where(jan: params[:ids].split(',')) 
# params[:ids] is a String
# params[:ids].split(',') will split string into array where finds character ','
```